# ExtJS 4 infinite grid hangs on "Loading..." when applying sort to a column

Tags: extjs

I have an infinite grid that works great by default, it fetches pages nicely through the results.

However, when I click a column header to define a sort order on one of the columns, the grid just hangs with the "Loading" message even though I'm sending back the exact same data as I did before the sort (I'm ignoring the "sort" varible on the server side just for testing puposes at the moment.)

Since this is for an open source project any additional source you may need to assist can be made available.

Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
John.

I get this request on the server:

```
"GET /lextjsapi/reader/tblname?_dc=1361204535173&page=1&start=0&limit=10&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22DESC%22%7D%5D HTTP/1.1" 200 832 "http://lextjs/sa-test/app.html"
```

This is is the PHP server side code:

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'total' => 1000, $model_name => $tblNameRows));
```

This is the code for the store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.tblnameStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'MyApp.model.tblname'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        remoteSort: true,
        storeId: 'tblnameStore',
        model: 'MyApp.model.tblname',
        buffered: true,
        leadingBufferZone: 10,
        pageSize: 10,
        purgePageCount: 0,
        trailingBufferZone: 10,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://lextjs/lextjsapi/reader/tblname',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'tblname'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
} });
```

This is the code for the grid:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyGridPanel2', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

height: 250,
width: 450,
title: 'My Grid Panel',
store: 'tblnameStore',

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        viewConfig: {

        },
        columns: [
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'id',
                text: 'Id'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                sortable: false,
                dataIndex: 'name',
                text: 'Name'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                sortable: false,
                dataIndex: 'address1',
                text: 'Address1'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                sortable: false,
                dataIndex: 'city',
                text: 'City'
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
} });
```

Comment: Look at the console of browser - what response comes from the server?

Comment: It asks for, and get back two json responses, these are the same as when it was unsorted since the server is currently ignoring the "sort" variable.

Comment: I have resolved the problem by removing leadingBufferZone,purgePageCount, and trailingBufferZone from the store.